# Inverse of linear transformation

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider a linear transformation 
$T: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ with $m$ is not equal to $n$.
Can we define $T$ as a invertible map. If not, then how I prove it?

I know if $n=m$ then $T$ is one to one iff $T$ is onto,
but not know when $n$ is not equal to $m$
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If T becomes invertible then T becomes isomorphic ,hence m=n

Answer (score 3):

We cannot, because an invertible linear map is an isomorphism, so it maps a basis onto a basis, and all bases of a vector space have the same number of elements.